# Query ignoring a condition in the "where" clause using time dimension

Tags: mysql, sql, time, dimension

I have to tables;

Table A with columns "id", "u_time" (of type datetime), "time_id" (of type int).
Table B (which was built as a time dimension), which holds all possible dates between 2000-2010, down to the hour (so, for every date there are 24 rows).
[Table B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00cKq.jpg)

I'm trying to update Table A to have the correct time_id for every id with the following query:

```
UPDATE A, B
SET A.time_id = B.time_id
WHERE DATE(A.u_time) = B.date
AND HOUR(A.u_time)=B.hour;
```

However, the query ignores the HOUR condition, and sets all values in A.time_id
to the time_id with the correct date but with hour 0.
[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6StUt.jpg)

How do I make the query not ignore the different hours?

Comment: You're only updating the `time_id` not the hour, day, etc. Is this what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use  an inner join

```
UPDATE A
Inner join B ON (DATE(A.u_time) = B.date AND HOUR(A.u_time)=B.hour)
SET A.time_id = B.time_id
```